# Throwing an IllegalArgumentException isn't working

Tags: java, generics, try-catch

So, for a homework assignment, our professor wants us to try inserting an integer into an array of Strings:

```
public boolean addPerson(V person, int number)throws IllegalArgumentException{
    if(numEntries < people.length){
        people[numEntries] = person;
        phones[numEntries] = number;
        numEntries++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    PhoneBook<String> names = new PhoneBook<String>();
    PhoneBook<Integer> ssn = new PhoneBook<Integer>();
    names.addPerson("john", 1235681213);
    ssn.addPerson(123324567, 2048);
    Integer soc = 132546789;
    try{
        names.addPerson(soc, 1996);
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        System.out.println("You cannot enter a Social Security Number "
            + "into the Name phone book!");
    }
```

But, this isn't working, and I still get the same error as without the try-catch.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**
Sorry guys, I probably should've included the code for the addPerson method. I don't really know how to deal with exceptions yet.

Comment: Dunno.  Does `addPerson` throw that exception?  Or any of its children exceptions?

Comment: @Makoto yes, it does

Comment: @Austin I would suggest adding more code for us to see, maybe posting the error that you see as well as the source code for the other classes so we can see whats going on.

Comment: Add the source for that method then.  Show us under what conditions it'd throw it, and prove that your input would satisfy that condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your professor likely wants you to observe is a compilation error.  An array's type is fixed at instantation time, and will not change.  The array will only ever accept whatever type it has been declared to accept, and nothing else.

Minor rant about exceptions to follow from here.

---

Let's have a quick chat about checked and unchecked exceptions.  There is a difference between these two, and mixing them up can be painful at times.

Let's start with the checked exceptions.  These are the exceptions that you **must** either explicitly catch yourself, or declare them to be thrown.  Things along those lines are `IOException`, `FileNotFoundException`*, and a few others - pretty much anything that extends from the `Exception` class.

Java is telling you that you have the ability to recover from this error, and you as a good developer should ensure that your program *does*.

There are also unchecked exceptions; anything that extends `RuntimeException` or `Error`.  These do **not** need to be declared to be thrown, as they occur during the runtime of the application, and there's really no guarantee if the program *should* recover from this error.  An example of this would be `ArithmeticException`; should your application really recover if it tried to divide by zero?  What state would it be in?

There are also some you really shouldn't be catching at all - what would you return to if you managed to catch an `OutOfMemoryError`?  There isn't much you really can do at that point!

Now, to your code:  you've **declared an unchecked exception to be thrown.** That's valid syntax, but Java isn't going to just arbitrarily throw the exception for you, because there isn't anything in that block of code that would just throw it.  At *worst*, you could get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, but that's no `IllegalArgumentException`.

In order to actually *throw* that unchecked exception, you'd need to explicitly throw it:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

...and you'd also need a good reason to do so.  Exceptions are expensive.

<sup>*:  I realize that `FileNotFoundException` **is-an** `IOException`.  It's still checked.</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much =) I realized after reading through the homework description again, it says to have the main method *attempt* to do the following, then compile and run.  I was assuming we wanted it to actually compile, but you're probably right.  And also thank you for the exception rant hahaha